# for loop using mysql statement

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I'm using pymysql in python to work with a mysql server, and I'm in need of some crossreferencing of different columns.

To do this I apply a for loop in python, with

```
for i in range(10):
    sqlstat = 'select refs from `pcite` where id = id_paper(i) ;'
```

But this doesn't work. The problem seems to be the iterater i. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Way around what? What doesn't work? is `id_paper(i)` supposed to be calling a function in your Python code? It isn't.

Comment: well the id_paper(i) should just give me specific id number

Comment: so like I want to do a series of mysql statements: select refs from `pcite`where id = 12312, select refs from `pcite`where id = 12323 etc.

Comment: But you're not calling that function. You just have a string containing that text. This is nothing to do with loops; if you want to actually execute code, you need to have it outside the string and interpolate the *result*.

Comment: Of course my script is a little more complicated than what I wrote, but I think the basic problem is contained in the question. How can I iterate statements like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment, this has nothing to do with loops. It is just that your code is not code, but simply a string. If you need a string to contain the result of calling a function, then you need to take the call outside of the string, and interpolate the result:

```
sqlstat = 'select refs from `pcite` where id = {};'.format(id_paper(i))
```

Note however that since this is an SQL statement, you should not be interpolating values at all, but passing them to the execute method:

```
sqlstat = 'select refs from `pcite` where id = %s;'
cursor.execute(sqlstat, [format(id_paper(i)])
```

Comment: Thank you, this is excactly what I needed. I'm sorry if my phrasing was unclear, I am not a programmer :)